# Backbone.History.extend( { loadUrl: ...} ) returning false for valid routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I'm trying to extend Backbone.History.loadUrl() to catch 404 errors:

```
var History = Backbone.History.extend({
        loadUrl: function() {
            var match = Backbone.History.prototype.loadUrl.apply(this, arguments);
            if (!match) {
                console.log('route not found');
            }
            return match;
        }
    }); 

(Backbone.history = new History).start();
```

This is based on the solution suggested here: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/308#issuecomment-9482299.

The problem I'm encountering is that when I call `(Backbone.history = new History).start()` on a valid route, it returns false. However, when I call `Backbone.history.start()` on the same route, it returns true.

When I add a debugger to the extended loadUrl method, `match` is set to false.

Any ideas about what's causing the discrepancy?

Comment: I suspect you've missed to add some route handlers to the history (by either calling `Backbone.history.route()` or creating a `Router` instance before starting the history) after re-crating and starting the history instance. Please step through the code and stop at the end of the `start()` method, step into `loadUrl()` and check if it's actually testing against a list of handlers.

Comment: In fact, if you literally write `(Backbone.history = new History).start();`, you must miss route handlers when `start()` runs.

Answer (score 1):

This should work instead.

```
var oldLoadUrl = Backbone.History.prototype.loadUrl;
_.extend(Backbone.History.prototype, {
  loadUrl : function () {
    var matched = oldLoadUrl.apply(this, arguments);
    if (!matched) {
      console.log('route not found');
    }
    return matched;
  }
});
```

Comment: can you kindly explain this solution a little? I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally write

```
(Backbone.history = new History).start();
```

your new History instance does not have any route handler. Thus it won't match any route at start leading to `false`. When you add handlers after `start()` and then navigate to that route it will trigger `true` of course.

You should either instantiate your router or add route handlers before `start()`ing  the history:

```
Backbone.history = new History();

// either 
new CustomRouter();
// or
Backbone.history.route(/^some-route/, function(){ console.log("at test-login"); })

history.start();
```